# Is it possible to Move a bootcamp partition from one drive to another?

Tags: bootcamp, hard-drive, partition, migration

When I got a new MacPro last year I formatted one of the additional (i.e. non-boot) drives with Bootcamp and installed Win 7 x64 on it. This set up has been working well these last 12+ months but I recently realised that the drive I've installed Windows on is a slow WD 'Green' eco-drive. Its rather slow at times as is only really designed for backups or storage rather than heavy use (I'm a .Net developer and use VMs extensively.

So what I'd like to now is move the Bootcamp partition onto the boot drive that came with the machine and keep everything running as it currently is. Is this going to be possible or am I looking at a day's work re-installing Windows and all my apps onto  a fresh Bootcamp partition on the main drive?

(Please say its possible) :-D

UPDATE August 2011:

I tried Winclone. Its no longer supported and fails everytime. Also not easily usable on OS X 10.7 Lion.

I've tried using the built-in Windows 7 backup functionality but this only seems to restore my files, not the OS environment.

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

It's a pleasure to tell you that it is, possible. I've done it successfully using [Winclone](http://download.cnet.com/Winclone/3000-2242_4-172338.html)

You can start rebreathing ;)

Comment: System imaging tools are built into Windows 7, so external tools are not required.

Comment: Warning: Winclone is not free, and the $20 "Basic" does not do the cloning job (and it's not clearly said on their website...). You have to buy the $40 "Standard" version to clone Bootcamp partitions.

Answer (score 1):

Create a system image using the Backup and Restore function of Windows 7. Make sure you store it externally (etc. a external hdd). Then, install Windows on the new partition on the boot drive, and restore it AFTER it has installed.

Remember to backup, in case you screw up and all your data is lost (I learnt it the hard way)

Comment: Thanks for this. Its bad that I'm still looking at a fair amount of time to repartition and install Windows, but I think I'll gain the time spent once I've got my windows install off that criminally slow drive ;-)